# How is Rip and Tear bonus damage in Jupiter Hell calculated?

Tags: jupiter-hell

The description for the Marine skill "Rip and Tear" states:

> Rip and tear! You prefer to handle your enemies face to face. Or chainsaw to face. Your percentage of Fury becomes a damage bonus to melee attacks (half at level 1), and you generate +1 Fury per melee kill (+2 per each additional level of this trait).

The bonus damage calculation is a little ambiguous however: is my Fury converted to a percent modifier, and that is added to my damage? Or is my percent of max Fury converted to said modifier? That is, suppose I have 20/40 Fury, and I have Rip and Tear 2. Is my bonus damage 20% (because I have 20 fury), or 50% (because I have half my max fury)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 50% of your Fury, so the bonus is 50%. If you had RaT level 1, that would be 25% (halved).

These things can be easily seen on the targeting info (top right), the damage presented there takes into account everything.

Comment: Oh snap, a response from the dev! Definitely getting the check mark.
This was my assumption. My most recent Melee Marine build died before I remembered to check this. I had read somewhere that Furious (which increases max Fury) synergized with Rip & Tear by increasing your max and thus increasing the damage. This didn't seem right, which is why I asked.